# Why aren't my puppet variables getting assigned by Vagrant's puppet.facter options?

Tags: puppet, vagrant, facter

**Given** that the following is config'd in my Vagrantfile:

```
puppet.facter = {
  'variableOne' => 'one',
  'variableTwo' => 'two'
}
```

... and the following is in the manifest:

```
notify{ "Got here with ${variableOne} and ${variableTwo}":}
```

**When** I run `vagrant up` (or `vagrant provision` if it's already up) I see the following line in the output:

```
==> default: Notice: Got here with and
```

**and when**  I add `--debug` to the vagrant command, I also see this in the output:

```
==> default: Running Puppet with default.pp...
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: Execute: FACTER_variableOne='one' FACTER_variableTwo='two' puppet apply --verbose --debug --manifestdir /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/manifests --detailed-exitcodes /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/manifests/default.pp (sudo=true)
```

**Why aren't the variables getting populated in the manifest?**

Example repo to reproduce: https://github.com/ericsmalling/vagrantpuppet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @SebastianWeigand, a coworker of mine, I've found that the use of cammel-case in the variable names was causing the problem.  Switching to "variableone" and "variabletwo" in both sides fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your notify is within a namespace. Can you try to access the facter variables in top scope via:

```
notify{ "Got here with ${::variableOne} and ${::variableTwo}":}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work either.   A coworker of fine found that eliminating camel-case in variable names seems to have fixed it though. (see my self-posted answer)

Comment: This was a possible issue in Puppet `2.7.x` and older. In `3.x`, you could only achieve shadowing by [explicitly overriding](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/variables.html#aside-why-do-everyones-manifests-seem-to-use-ipaddress) the values in the manifest (outside any class, in the node block if used, or in the class/define that tries to access the values).